# Android Testing: Which testing Framework?

Tags: android, testing

I am new in android development and I have a basic app running, I would like to test it. Which framework is used out there a lot? The one that comes with Android itself? I found this: 
http://robospock.org/

It seems cool as it is based on spock.

Thanks

Comment: The downvotes are because you are asking to recommend an off-site resource and it is opinion based. You should read [The Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) about what to ask and what not to ask and how.

Comment: UI testing frameworks or unit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many frameworks, here is my suggestions
**Unit Testing**
You can use JUnit with [RoboElectric](http://robolectric.org/) and [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) as mocking framework

**UI Testing**
You can use [Magneto](https://github.com/EverythingMe/magneto) which is a great python-based testing framework for Android apps

Hope it helps.